# Open file as root and user in Linux

Tags: c, linux

I currently have two programs that access that use `mkfifo` to create a named pipe. Both processes will read and write to and from that pipe. It is created from one process that runs as root with `umask(0000);` and permissions `0777`.

When both processes run as user, it works fine. When one process runs as root I cannot open the pipe from the other process with `errno` set to `EPERM` (Permission denied).

Is there a way to work around this issue?

Comment: Try using seteuid to temporarily change to user.

Comment: I do not know which user will open these files (multiuser system). So that is not a real solution...

Comment: Have you confirmed (with `ls -l`) that after the root process creates the fifo, it does indeed have mode `rw-rw-rw-`?

Comment: It has "rwxrwxrwx" and the containing directory (in tmp) has "drwxrwxrwx"

Comment: Is it possible you have a race condition? 1. root process creates fifo. 2. user process attempts to open fifo, and fails. 3. root process changes fifo's mode to allow world read/write.

Comment: With the root process running, can you say `echo x > the_fifo` or `head -1 < the_fifo`?  Do they get "Permission denied", too?

Comment: Problem was the `NOATIME` flag...

Comment: Note that you don’t need execute permission on a FIFO.